# Using imagejpeg() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I am migrating my existing PHP program to Laravel. I know the upload should be `$request->files->store('images');` but this doesn't compress the images beforehand.

I have found Intervention Image plugin for Laravel but I don't want to use it because I want it to be pure PHP only.

My working code from pure PHP was:

```
$info = getimagesize($tmpFilename);
if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpFilename);
} else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($tmpFilename);
} else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($tmpFilename);
}

imagejpeg($image, $path, 60);
```

I know the images get saved at /storage/app/public/ so I used that path for imagejpeg as well. This is my laravel code:

```
$tmp_file = $inner->getPathName();
imagejpeg($tmp_file, '/storage/app/public/images/hehe.jpg', 60);
```

But it doesn't work. It only says
`imagejpeg(/storage/app/public/images/hehe.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think `storage/app/public/images` can be accessed via `public_path('images')` so you could try `public_path('images/hehe.jpg') ` instead of hacking your way around getting the path

Comment: @apokryfos it still says ```imagejpeg(C:\Users\Personal\laravel\public\images/hehe.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory```

Comment: My mistake. Should be `public_path('storage/images/hehe.jpg')`. This assumes you've ran `php artisan storage:link` beforehand.

Comment: @apokryfos but that makes the files accessible to the public right? Example domain.com/images/hehe.jpg can be viewed by a site visitor

Comment: yes `domain.com/storage/images/hehe.jpg` willl be public. You can actually get the  correct URL using `Storage::disk('public')->url('images/hehe.jpg')`